# Dropdownlist selectedindexchanged firing on button click, asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, postback

I have a `dropdownlist` in my page. the `AutoPostBack` property is `true`.
The `dropdownlist` shows *list of users*. when any user is selected, his details are shown in `textboxes` below.

> Problem is when the update button is clicked, the `dropdownlist` **postsback** and all the `textboxes` are reset.

How can i prevent this?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUserList" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="True"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUserList_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdate" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" Text="UPDATE"
    OnClick="btnUpdateUser_Click" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is your code in populating the dropdownlist?

Comment: I am populating the dropdownlist in page load. But populating it is not the issue. changing of selected index is the issue.

Comment: is it necessary to postback? coz we can prevent the postback for it not to reset.. or maybe you can put your code inside `If Not IsPostBack` on pageload so that it wont change the selected index

Comment: Sorry, zzzzz, wrong answer.

Comment: @santubangalore - Can you show the code which populates your dropdown?

Comment: Hi Rahul singh, populating it is not the issue. changing of selected index is the issue. When the button is clicked, how do we prevent the dropdownlist selectedindex from changing

Comment: Hi zzzzz, please stop commenting if you don't understand the problem. Let  someone who understand come in and comment.

Answer (score 0):

Bind dropdownlist in

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
// code to bind dropdown
}
```